# I want a usb system that will physically reboot my computer

Tags: power

I sometimes work remotely. It is a pain as my computer will sometimes crash and not reboot. I also have a second computer nearby which is more reliable.

I'd like to build a system that will press the power button on my first computer from the second. It should be able to keep the button pressed for a few seconds to ensure a full power shutdown.

I'm a software engineer with little electrical engineering experience. I'm quite comfortable with everything related to programming, but the hardware components elude me. What should I look for?

I thought of buying something like a raspberry pi and using some of the board io to activate a coil which would somehow be fitted to my pc box, but I'm totally unsure of what I'm talking about.

Comment: Well... Turns out that it is today that my boss told me that I can`t work from home anymore. FML

Answer (score 4):

Search for a "managed power strip" ([example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005D55HKU))

Answer (score 4):

Simply glue a finger shaped piece of plastic to the front of the second computer's CD tray. Place the second computer facing the first computer so that, when its CD tray opens, the 'finger' presses the button. Then log in and eject the CD!

Comment: That is a great suggestion! It is really hard to guess that it is coming from a robotics guy :)

Comment: I can sell you a robotic finger too if you want!

Answer (score 3):

There is another question on superuser that may help you without having to resort to making something.

https://superuser.com/questions/319859/remotely-turning-on-or-rebooting-a-frozen-computer

Answer (score 1):

I do this all the time. I use a Phidgets [InterfaceKit 0/0/8](http://www.phidgets.com/products.php?category=9&product_id=1017_1) which is maybe overkill for you, but for me I can control 8 different things. (I have a plethora of various boards I'm working on and each will have either a relay for reset or a relay to cycle power. The board is connected to a "control" computer (something that never does anything but run the relays, so it should never fall off the network.  I do have my workstation's reset and power lines hooked up to two different relays on this unit, but I very very rarely use it; the workstation is generally just a compiler/NX server and as such almost never needs to be reset. The relay board is controlled via USB and there are libraries available for many languages. I use the Python library.  The libraries are meant to be used with ALL of their I/O blocks so it's a little overkill for a relay board, but it gets the job done and it works quite well.

Now this is only one method. Managed power strips are also useful, and I have a couple of these as well for switching AC. One of them is set up to cycle power to any of the equipment connecting my system to the internet, and is on a cellular modem connection. (It should never happen, but I've seen switches and DSL modems hang... good luck fixing that from remote!) The specific ones I have are no longer sold, but Cyclades AlterPath PDUs are available on eBay for the right price. APC, BayTech and numerous off-brand companies make these things. They're generally serially-controlled with a very simple protocol. eBay's useful here, and the term you're looking for is Power Distribution Unit or PDU.

Generally speaking you don't want to be resetting a PC willy-nilly, as I'm sure you know. I don't know which OS you're using but you might want to try adjusting the settings so that the power switch performs a proper ACPI shutdown *without* prompting you... that way the OS will restart the machine, but it'll be done after properly shutting down the OS.

If you're running Linux you could make a little USB peripheral using a PIC or something that sends the alt-s-s-s-u-b key sequence which is about as close to a low-level reset as you can get and still save most of your work. I tend to reset a system only as a last resort, and on your workstation that should be almost never.